# Solving the $CP^N$ model in large $N$ limit

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, large-n

I have trouble filling in the essential step of solving the $CP^N$ model in large $N$ limit, described on Page 84 to 86 of Michael Dine's *Supersymmetry and String Theory*.

The Lagrangian is given by
$$ \mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{g^2} [|D_\mu z_i|^2 -\lambda(x)(|z_i|^2-1)] $$

Without explanation, Michael claimed that

1. the effective action after you integrate out $z_i$ is
   $$ \Gamma_{eff} = -N \operatorname{tr} \log (-D^2-\lambda) - \frac{1}{g^2}\int d^2x \lambda $$
   What is $D$ here? The propagator?
2. After this, then you take the large $N$ limit, fixing $g^2N$. It is claimed that the path integral is dominated by a single field configuration, which solves
   $$ \frac{\delta \Gamma_{eff}}{\delta \lambda} =0. $$
   Alternately, you can set the gauge field to zero, and get
   $$ N \int \frac{d^2k}{(2\pi)^2} \frac{1}{k^2+\lambda^2} = \frac{1}{g^2}.$$
   I'm totally confused here. How did Michael derive this integral equation of $\lambda$?

Answer (score 1):

I have some understanding which may be not so accurate.

(1) Here the $D^2$ is just the inverse propagator, which represents the eigenvalue matrices $p^2$. The effective action $\Gamma_{eff}$ is integrated as $z_i$ should be rescaled by factor $g$. Would that be any question about the integration process?

(2) Once you get the effective action, then you make variation about $\lambda$ and set it to be zero:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\frac{\delta \Gamma_{eff}}{\delta\lambda(x)} &=-\frac{1}{g^2}-N\frac{\delta(\log\det(-D^2-\lambda))}{\delta\lambda} \\
&= -\frac{1}{g^2}-Ntr((-D^2-\lambda)^{-1}) \\
&=-\frac{1}{g^2}+N\int\frac{dk^2}{(2\pi)^2}\frac{1}{k^2+\lambda}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
So set it equal to 0 and you get the result. Here the variation of logdet is from the $Gravitation\ and\ cosmology$ of Weinberg Page 107, but actually the sign before $N$ has some issue. I should concern it later. The last step follows from the propagator definition, but I am not sure it's accurate.